# R: how to separate date-time data types

Tags: r

My data set is "weather":

[image]

I need to calculate the average time and date.
First I tried to separate the date and time into to different columns by:
`weather$Date <- as.Date(weather$Time,"%m/%d/%Y")`
but then I got NA for some of the data.
I did the same for the time and got 00:00

any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Time variable in your dataset is formatted `"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"` but your code's format is `"%m/%d/%Y"`. Perhaps, that's why you're getting `NAs`.

```
Humidity <- c(37.79, 42.34, 52.16, 44.57, 43.83, 44.59)
Rain <- c(0.971360441, 1.10969716, 1.064475853, 0.953183435, 0.98878849, 0.939676146)
Time <- c("27/01/2015 15:44","23/02/2015 23:24", "31/03/2015 19:15", "20/01/2015 20:52", "23/02/2015 07:46", "31/01/2015 01:55")

weather <- data.frame(Humidity, Rain, Time)

  Humidity      Rain             Time
1    37.79 0.9713604 27/01/2015 15:44
2    42.34 1.1096972 23/02/2015 23:24
3    52.16 1.0644759 31/03/2015 19:15
4    44.57 0.9531834 20/01/2015 20:52
5    43.83 0.9887885 23/02/2015 07:46
6    44.59 0.9396761 31/01/2015 01:55

Hours <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(weather$Time,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M",tz="")) ,format = "%H:%M")
#output
"15:44" "23:24" "19:15" "20:52" "07:46" "01:55"

Dates <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(weather$Time,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M",tz="")) ,format = "%d/%d/%Y")
#output
"27/27/2015" "23/23/2015" "31/31/2015" "20/20/2015" "23/23/2015" "31/31/2015"

weather$Dates <- Dates
    weather$Hours <- Hours

#output

    Humidity  Rain         Time         Dates    Hours
1    37.79 0.9713604 27/01/2015 15:44 27/01/2015 15:44
2    42.34 1.1096972 23/02/2015 23:24 23/02/2015 23:24
3    52.16 1.0644759 31/03/2015 19:15 31/03/2015 19:15
4    44.57 0.9531834 20/01/2015 20:52 20/01/2015 20:52
5    43.83 0.9887885 23/02/2015 07:46 23/02/2015 07:46
6    44.59 0.9396761 31/01/2015 01:55 31/01/2015 01:55
```

You can now drop the `Time` variable by doing:

```
weather <- subset(weather, select = c(1,2,4,5))

    Humidity  Rain      Dates   Hours
1    37.79 0.9713604 27/01/2015 15:44
2    42.34 1.1096972 23/02/2015 23:24
3    52.16 1.0644759 31/03/2015 19:15
4    44.57 0.9531834 20/01/2015 20:52
5    43.83 0.9887885 23/02/2015 07:46
6    44.59 0.9396761 31/01/2015 01:55
```

This should do.

Comment: Thank you Abdou! when I try to separate the time with: 

`weather$Hour<-format(as.POSIXct(weather$Time) ,format = "%H:%M") ` 
I get "00:00"....can you think why?

Comment: @shiran, can you please attach the actual snippet of the data (and not an image of it), so I can try and replicate the code on my computer?

Comment: Hi @shiran, try this: `format(as.POSIXct(strptime(weather$Time,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M",tz="")) ,format = "%H:%M")`. Please note that the year in your data contains 4 digits, and in order to factor that in you have to use upper case %Y in the format of the `Time` variable. Once that's done you should be able to grab the time out of the variable.

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me!!!  now when I try to use mean on weather$Hours it says _argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA_ .... how can I calc the average Date and Hours?

Comment: @shiran, you technically cannot calculate the average of a date or hour. What you can do is find the most frequent hour or date during which the `Humidity` and `Rain` variables were collected. Also, you could convert the `Hours` variable into seconds, but that still would not really give you a meaningful average from the data. What are you looking to do with the Date and Time variables actually?